AWS SAM: force repdeploy function even no changes
I want to redeploy all my lambda functions even code change or not. When there is no code change, Cloudformation complains empty change set and does not redeploy my function.
Is it possible to force redeploy using AWS SAM? Or any workaround for this case?

This behaviour of SAM is expected as it will just result to necessary consumption of deployment nodes on their side. To prevent your builds from failing, you could use the --no-fail-on-empty-changeset flag of sam deploy command.
UPDATE
You can force a new upload of your artifacts by combining touch command with --force-upload flag
find . -type f -name "*.js" \
  ! -path "./node_modules/*" -exec touch {} +

sam deploy --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
  --force-upload


Option --no-fail-on-empty-changeset only prevent SAM CLI from failing, but the function is not redeployed.
I'm trying to pass different Description for each time deploy. Function Description belongs to configuration so I suppose SAM will redeploy the funciton.

@WindRise, I thought your problem was about the pipeline failing when there are no changes. Anyways, what you could do is either 1). If you are using javascript, force a rebuild of your bundles. 2). For other languages, temporarily change the function-level MemorySize and just return it back mate.

I think changing MemorySize may work, similar to changing Function Description.

@WindRise, that will require configuration check though, the solution above guarantees a forced deployment haha

Look like your update solution is not working. I see the package is published to S3 but still empty changeset and function is not updated.
